# resize the text in drop down

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have drop down in which few text is long and due to this size has become too long.

```js
var name1 = "A",
    name2 = "B",
    name3 = "C";

var s = document.getElementById('names');
s.children[0].innerText = name1;
s.children[1].innerText = name2;
s.children[2].innerText = name3;
```

```html
    <select id="names">
        <option value="a">fill1</option>
        <option value="b">fill2</option>
        <option value="c">fill3</option>
    </select>
```

How can I resize the drop-down?

Comment: So what do you actually want to achieve?    if you change `var name1 ="A"` to `var name1 ="Aaaaaaa"` or anything else, it will show....

Comment: Whats the problem exactly? Going by your example in jsfiddle there does not seem to be a problem

Comment: I think you're trying to get a key/value select structure?

Comment: please use this https://jsfiddle.net/sandeepkapalawai/1Lmcgro0/

Comment: Please take a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Comment: @SaucedApples excatly if the text is like aaaaaaaa......... and it needs to wrap to the size of drop down

Comment: Then edit your question to be specific

Answer (score 0):

If you set a class with css to give it a specified width. Or just put some style on your select element.

```
<select id="names" style=width:100px class='setMyWidth'>
<option value="a">fill1</option>
<option value="b">fill2</option>
<option value="c">fill3</option>
```

you can also create a css class.

```
.setMyWidth{width: 100px;}
```

note: without any external library it is not possible to word wrap your dropdown box. Shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTs42/792/) is what you are trying to achieve. That is only possible with the external library [found over here](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/)

Comment: its resizing to only drop down size not the text wrap size, i am just looking for text wrap in the drop down https://jsfiddle.net/sandeepkapalawai/1Lmcgro0/2/

Comment: take a look at this... http://jsfiddle.net/acrnP/ 

If the above isnt the solution for you can you please be more specific?
im not sure what you mean with text wrap? Do you want to change the size of the dropdownbox if its collapsed? Or do you want to keep the size when its opened and not expanding to full text width?

Comment: Yes, iam referring about the size of drop down should  be same when in case if the text is tooo larger than drop drop then in this case the text should adjust as the size of drop down and the extra text which seems more size should break in to next line

Comment: just similar to this one http://jsfiddle.net/ZTs42/792/ you can see the option 7 in drop down is wrapped

Comment: Then you have found your solution right? Ive editted my answer. Look at the note in my answer

Comment: Sorry , no it was not solved, i could see the action size is less than the drop list , what am referring is both the drop down size the text even if it larger than drop down, it should adjust in the list like breaking in to  next line.